# Duplicating a hard disk

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I'd like to simply duplicate a hard disk drive to another hard disk drive of the same size.

I know I can simply do:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

(or whatever the names of the drives are in `/dev`).

Is there a better tool for this which will show me visual progress? If I'm only using 30GB of the drive, will it only take as long as it takes to transfer 30GB or will it take as long as the drive capacity?

Comment: You say drive, but your command use partitions

Comment: So a drive would be `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, right? That's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make GNU `dd` show you progress - to quote the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd):

> Sending a USR1 signal to a running `dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
$ kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill $pid
```

Schily's `dd` ([sdd](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/sdd.html)) has a similar option and uses SIGQUIT by default (`Ctrl+\`).

Regarding your second question: Yes, `dd` just copies all the blocks if used by the filesystem or not - which takes DEVICE_CAPACITY/TRANSFER_RATE seconds.

If you want to avoid copying unused disk blocks you can use `tar`:

```
# cd /mnt/sda
# tar -c -f - . | tar -C /mnt/sdb -x -f -
```

GNU `tar` also has timing options:

```
# tar -c -f - . --totals=SIGQUIT | tar -C /mnt/sdb -x -f - \
                                      --totals --totals=SIGQUIT
```

Thus you get read/write statistics when hitting `Ctrl+\` and at the end.

Another possibility is to use [`parted`](http://www.gnu.org/s/parted/) or [`gparted`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) for copying a filesystem - which should be done in a efficient way with filesystems it has enough knowledge of. At least `gparted` should display a nice graphical progress dialog.

Comment: I'll need to copy all the blocks then, as I have HFS+, NTFS, and ext4 partitions on the same drive.

Comment: `Ctrl+`? `Ctrl+\​`? No, that sends SIGQUIT. There's no key for SIGHUP. An easier, and generally more robust way of copying files on a Linux system is `cp -a . /mnt/sdb`, or `rsync -aP . /mnt/sdb` if you want a progress indicator.

Comment: @Gilles, yes `Ctrl+backslash` is SIGQUIT - mixed that up - I will update the question. `cp -a` is not portable - GNU `cp` has `-a` but it is not in POSIX. A correct implementation of `cp -a` should work as well as the `tar` pipe (modulo use of `--totals` option) - but why should it be *more* robust?

Comment: @maxschlepzig My recommendation of `cp -a` is from an experience a few years ago, transferring home directories of people with a propensity for using advanced features of anything they touched between filesystems that weren't supported by the same unix variant. GNU `cp -a` over NFS caused no complaint. `tar` choked on files with a hard link count >1 whose path was >100 bytes. `pax` missed named sockets and a few other oddities. I forget what other solutions I tried. I remember some not preserving file access times, too.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use `ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb` which support errors and have a progress bar

Comment: Probably need the `-f` flag for GNU ddrescue to overwrite destination device

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use the `pv` program (it is on the repos of all the distros i know of). It will give you an nice progress bar.

```
$dd if=/dev/sda |pv -s 80g |dd of=/dev/sdb
```

with the `-s` you add the amount of the original prtition/disk you are copy (the `if` in the dd command). If you wouldn't put the `-s` argument it just give you a moving bar to indicate that data is moving, but wouldn't give you how much.

of course add `sudo` if you need.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`, twice: you can simply write `</dev/sda pv -s 80g >/dev/sdb`.